# Not able to click on dropdown through xpath or CSS?

Tags: xpath, css-selectors, click, webdriver, dropdown

This is a dropdown which I am not able to click through xpath or CSS selector.

My HTML code:-

```
<button class="userInfo dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-reactid=".0.0.0.1:$=11:$1.1" type="button"> <span class="sr-only" data-reactid=".0.0.0.1:$=11:$1.1.0">Toggle dropdown</span> <span class="caret" data-reactid=".0.0.0.1:$=11:$1.1.1"/> <span data-reactid=".0.0.0.1:$=11:$1.1.2" style="letter-spacing:-.3em;"/>
```

Code I have tried:-

`driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@data-reactid='.0.0.0.1:$=11:$1.1']")).click()‌​;`

but I am getting error says:-

> it can not find such xpath

[image]

Comment: <button class="userInfo dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-reactid=".0.0.0.1:$=11:$1.1" type="button">
<span class="sr-only" data-reactid=".0.0.0.1:$=11:$1.1.0">Toggle dropdown</span>
<span class="caret" data-reactid=".0.0.0.1:$=11:$1.1.1"/>
<span data-reactid=".0.0.0.1:$=11:$1.1.2" style="letter-spacing:-.3em;"/>

Comment: I tried  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@data-reactid='.0.0.0.1:$=11:$1.1']")).click();      but error says it can not find such xpath

Comment: Is the element inside a iframe? If it is, you need switch your driver to access the frame

Comment: Because there is nothing wrong with you xpath, also i tested it local in a webpage and works

Answer (score 0):

There may be a possiblity of iframe:-

driver.switchTo().frame("provide frame name or location");

Refer below for more info regarding switch on frame:-

http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/handling-iframes-using-selenium-webdriver/

OR

There is a possiblity that your xpath is not fine or returning more than 1 element to selenium. In this condition selenium will be confuse that on which element selenium should click . so check your xpath again

Hope it will help you :)